# too many arguments for method apply: (car: play.api.data.Form[models.CarroFormData])

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this error bellow and can't find the solution or how to debug what's being passed to apply.
Can anyone help?

> too many arguments for method apply: (car:
>   play.api.data.Form[models.CarroFormData])(implicit messages:
>   play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class
>   index

Controller Form

```
def add = Action { implicit request =>
    CarroForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      // if any error in submitted data
      errorForm => Ok(views.html.admin.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[Carro])),
      data => repo.create(carro.name, carro.description, carro.img, carro.keywords).map { _ =>
          // If successful, we simply redirect to the index page.
          Redirect(routes.application.index)
        })
  }
```

This is the Model

```
package dal

import javax.inject.{ Inject, Singleton }
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import models._

import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }

/**
 * A repository for people.
 *
 * @param dbConfigProvider The Play db config provider. Play will inject this for you.
 */
@Singleton
class CarroRepository @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  // We want the JdbcProfile for this provider
  private val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]

  // These imports are important, the first one brings db into scope, which will let you do the actual db operations.
  // The second one brings the Slick DSL into scope, which lets you define the table and other queries.
  import dbConfig._
  import driver.api._

  /**
   * Here we define the table. It will have a name of people
   */
  private class CarroTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Carro](tag, "carro") {

    /** The ID column, which is the primary key, and auto incremented */
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    /** The name column */
    def name = column[String]("name")

    /** The description column */
    def description = column[String]("description")

    /** The img column */
    def img = column[String]("img")

    /** The keywords column */
    def keywords = column[String]("keywords")

    /**
     * This is the tables default "projection".
     *
     * It defines how the columns are converted to and from the Person object.
     *
     * In this case, we are simply passing the id, name and page parameters to the Person case classes
     * apply and unapply methods.
     */
    def * = (id, name, description, img, keywords) <> ((Carro.apply _).tupled, Carro.unapply)
  }

  /**
   * The starting point for all queries on the people table.
   */
  private val carro = TableQuery[CarroTable]

  /**
   * Create a person with the given name and age.
   *
   * This is an asynchronous operation, it will return a future of the created person, which can be used to obtain the
   * id for that person.
   */
  def create(name: String, description: String, img:String, keywords: String): Future[Carro] = db.run {
    // We create a projection of just the name and age columns, since we're not inserting a value for the id column
    (carro.map(p => (p.name, p.description, p.img, p.keywords))
      // Now define it to return the id, because we want to know what id was generated for the person
      returning carro.map(_.id)
      // And we define a transformation for the returned value, which combines our original parameters with the
      // returned id
      into ((nameAge, id) => Carro(id, nameAge._1, nameAge._2, nameAge._3, nameAge._4))
    // And finally, insert the person into the database
    ) += (name, description, img, keywords)
  }

  /**
   * List all the people in the database.
   */
  def list(): Future[Seq[Carro]] = db.run {
    carro.result
  }

}
```

package models

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Carro(id: Long, name:String, description:String, img:String, keywords:String)

case class CarroFormData(name: String, description: String, img: String, keywords: String)

object CarroForm {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "description" -> nonEmptyText,
      "img" -> nonEmptyText,
      "keywords" -> nonEmptyText
    )(CarroFormData.apply)(CarroFormData.unapply)
  )
}

object Carros {

  var carros: Seq[Carro] = Seq()

  def add(carros: Carro): String = {
    carros = carros :+ carro.copy(id = carro.length) // manual id increment 
    "User successfully added"
  }

  def delete(id: Long): Option[Int] = {
    val originalSize = carro.length
    carro = carro.filterNot(_.id == id)
    Some(originalSize - carro.length) // returning the number of deleted users
  }

  def get(id: Long): Option[Carro] = carro.find(_.id == id)

  def listAll: Seq[Carro] = carro

  implicit val carroFormat = Json.format[Carro]

}
```

View Code

```
@(car: Form[CarroFormData])(implicit messages: Messages)

@import helper._

@main(new Main("Car Dealers", "Compra e venda de carros", "logo.png", "carro, compra, venda")) {
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
@form(routes.AdminCarro.add()) {
        @inputText(person("name"))
        @inputText(person("description"))
        @inputText(person("img"))
        @inputText(person("keywords"))
        )

        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Car"/>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: it looks like this `views.html.admin.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[Carro])` takes just one parameter `(car: play.api.data.Form[models.CarroFormData])` and you passed 2

Comment: Already tried removing one of them from the call, but didn't solve the issue, I'll place the view code in the edit.

Comment: so what does the error look like when you use: `Ok(views.html.admin.index(errorForm)` ? When you try to visit page through browser it usually shows you where the error is.

Comment: Now it passed that error and showed another one... But I managed to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your controller code:

```
def add = Action { implicit request =>
  CarroForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
    // if any error in submitted data
    errorForm => Ok(views.html.admin.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[Carro])),
    data => repo.create(carro.name, carro.description, carro.img, carro.keywords).map { _ =>
      // If successful, we simply redirect to the index page.
      Redirect(routes.application.index)
    }
  )
}
```

At the `errorForm`, you are calling the index view with two arguments:

```
Ok(views.html.admin.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[Carro]))
```

But your view declares just one argument:

```
@(car: Form[CarroFormData])(implicit messages: Messages)
```

Just remove the `Seq.empty[Carro]` from the call in your controller and everything should work as expected. If you still getting the same error, see if there are other places where this view is called the same wrong way (with two arguments) or try to `sbt clean` your project before `sbt run`.